# Error: missing classes in xml files Android Studio Androidx

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

How to fix these missing classes?

I migrate my project to Androidx, but in the xml files I have these errors (ExpandableHeightGridView, TextView, SliderLayout, StickyScrollView, NotificationExpandableHeightListView, ExpandableHeightListView, and EditText Java classes are there):

Missing classes. The following classes could not be found:

```
com.google.android.gms.appset.R
ExpandableHeightGridView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
SliderLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
StickyScrollView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
NotificationExpandableHeightListView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
ExpandableHeightListView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
EditText (Change to android.widget.EditText, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Dependencies library:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.6.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:3.5.2'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia:library:1.1'
implementation 'com.guigarage:animations:0.7'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.4'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0"

implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.4@aar'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-beta02'

implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

implementation (platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2'))
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:22.2.0'

}
```

Why do?

Answer (score 0):

**Invalided and caches restart Android Studio**
*Clean and Re-build your project*

**Step 1: **
*Build.gradle(modual app)- Top side*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Step 2: **
*Buld.gradle(project_name) - Bellow dependency side*

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}}
```

*Syns your project and run.*

*I hope your project running successfully.*

*step 3: One more process check your git-hub. And check first git-ignore file. If xml file present in side then remove from side*

*step 4: And your app just Right Click and select option refactor then select option "Migrating in Androidx"*

Comment: These are very bad. These recommendations worked before Androidx. jcenter has been out of date for years.

Comment: mavenCentral() also added sir